# Stretch Factor for SNIa

Tags: astrophysics, supernova, photometry

How do I compute the stretch factor for a Supernova Ia ?

Data I have : Redshift, Points on the light curve, Rise time (∆m=2), Fall time (∆m=2), Time from the peak day for an inflection point in the light curve.

Is there a quantitative formulation for stretch factor in terms of other parameters or can it only be obtained by scaling and fitting the template light curve ?